# Tag synonyms should show the parent tag's description in the tags page

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki, tags-page

When looking through the tags page, tag synonyms are shown in the list. When you hover over them, they show the description for the parent tag. For example, when hovering over the [godfather](/questions/tagged/godfather) tag on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), it correctly shows the tag wiki excerpt for the [the-godfather](/questions/tagged/the-godfather) tag:

[image: Godfather tag synonym on Movies & TV]

However, it does not show the full description underneath it, like the parent tag does:

[image: Godfather tags on Movies & TV]

To make the tags and synonyms easier to navigate, can the full descriptions please be inherited too?

Comment: To reproduce the second image, go to the [Movies Tag page](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tags) and type `godfather`. It's a touch odd to include a synonym in that case without at least showing what it's mapped too.

Comment: Given that this quirk can be used to spot synonyms more easily, I'd object to its being removed unless some other way to discern them was added. For example, simply showing both tags in the main list and an arrow or something between to signify the synonym direction.