# Missing tag descriptions on random tags in tags page

Tags: bug, tags

In the tags page, the description and question count of some tags are missing. This also happens when these tags are searched. They seem to be random.

Is this a bug or an intended feature?

[image: Tags page]
[image: 20k tag]
[image: search results]

Comment: Somewhat related: [Tag synonyms should show the parent tag's description in the tags page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234261/tag-synonyms-should-show-the-parent-tags-description-in-the-tags-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some are synonyms if you click on them you will redirected to the tag which they are attached and that tag have usage guidance and some tags legitimately don't have tag wiki and usage guidance.

Comment: In my opinion those synonyms should be hidden (as they once were I think)

Comment: @PatrickHofman mmhh but if some user don't have idea that his tag which he once used is now a synonym and he can't find about the newly tag about that particular topic? instead I think they should show this tag is now a synonym by whatever sign.